# What does this icon mean, in the stock messenger app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, instant-messaging

Pretty straightforward; when viewing the list of recent contacts/conversations, the stock messenger app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 shows this icon, but for only the one conversation.

I don't know if it's a button, or notification, but I'm afraid to touch it.

Can anyone explain what it is/does?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I believe I've found it.

As per [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/199971-grey-circles-x-appear-text-list.html) thread (*for example*) on the interwebs, it has to do with the Tango app, which I've recently installed.

Essentially, since Tango integrates with your phone like a parasite, when a contact is not available to use Tango the `(x)` icon indicates this in the stock SMS app.

Having cross-referenced this against similar threads, it seems to be the answer.